# Conditionally calling React components without import declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I know the way I'm doing this is overly complex for the task, but I'm learning React in a context I know. And I'm really stumbling over how to get components to render conditionally.

I tried a few variations.

Basically, I have a generic `Document` component that I want to generate the content of based upon the URL.

```
  return (
    <>
      <Title title={articleTitle} subtitle={articleSubtitle} />
      <div className="body">
        <Author author={articleAuthor} date={articleDate} />
        <ConditionalComponentGoesHere />
      </div>
      <MoreContent />
    </>
  );
}

export default Document;
```

The conditional components look like this:

```
function ArticleOne() {
  return (
    <>
    JSX content
    </>
```

I've tried React Router but that doesn't render anything. The Navigation, higher up in the tree, is using it and maybe that's impacting it - but I'm not getting any console errors.

```
    <>
      <Title title={articleTitle} subtitle={articleSubtitle} />
      <div className="body">
        <Author author={articleAuthor} date={articleDate} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/article-one" element={<ArticleOne />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <MoreContent />
    </>
```

A better solution for me would be to have the article paths in a JSON file and to render them based on that. I couldn't figure it out alongside inline importing. `React.lazy()` delivered a blank screen with no console errors and then using the component name as a variable seems unallowed (`<{componentName} />`).

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? It's been a real head scratcher.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) for rendering url parameter in a component.